# What determines ownership of Tomcat's catalina.out?

Tags: permissions, tomcat, systemd

I have an instance of Tomcat 9 running on Ubuntu 20.04.

In my `systemd` service file for Tomcat 9, I set Tomcat to run as a utility user 'sally' and log to `/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out`:

```
[Service]
User=sally
Group=sally

SyslogIdentifier=
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out
StandardError=append:/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out
```

I notice that when `catalina.out` is created, it's owned by root:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  admin  83K May 25 11:59 catalina.out
```

This surprises me; since 'sally' is running the Tomcat process (which I confirmed by checking the `ps` list), I would expect that user to also own the log file, and that was in fact the case on a similar 16.04 system I previously ran.

The permissions of the `/var/log/tomcat9/` directory are

```
drwxr-s--- 2 sally  admin 12K May 25 14:53 /var/log/tomcat9/
```

Notice there's no 'setuid' bit on the directory, so `catalina.out` isn't inheriting ownership from the directory.  Even if it were, it should be inheriting 'sally'.

What determines the ownership of Tomcat's `catalina.out` log, particularly under `systemd`?

Answer (score 2):

The logs are created when Tomcat is started by systemd, ie. root.  Then, for safety reasons, the process changes ownership.

The catalina.out log is a PITA, for someone interested in rotating it.  There is no way except when restarting Tomcat.  When I was running Tomcat, I made sure the standard output was kept to a minimum, by forcing the developers to take good care of the logging of their applications.  Whenever they missed something, it ended up in catalina.out.